# c format strings: printf argument containing format specifiers

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int b= 37;
    char a=10, str[32] = "deva%x %x", buf[32];
    snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), str);
    printf("%s", buf);
    printf("\n %p", &b);
    return 0;
}
```

Ouput:
deva80482b9 40020930
0xbfb80aac

Wondering how printf is working here & what is the value it's printing. Does it have any significance ??

Answer (score 2):

This is undefined behavior, since the arguments passed to `snprintf()` don't match the format string.

No further analysis of what happens in general is very interesting, since what happens is *undefined* and might change from one compilation of the program to another.

The most likely explanation is that `printf()` proceeds as if the arguments where there, reading data from foo-knows-where.

Comment: I always assumed the first argument in the printf statement is the one that should contain format specifiers, is my understanding is not correct.

Comment: Sure, but this is a call to [`snprintf()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf), which is not the same function as `printf()`. This formats to a size-limited string buffer (which is what the prefix `sn` typically means).

Comment: Yup, got confused. Wondering will it try to read data in stack ??

Comment: @Deva That is undefined. Nobody knows, except maybe the people who implemented your particular combination of compiler and standard library. You can of course disassemble and/or debug the program to find out what it does, but that doesn't tell you much in general.

Comment: @Deva You can make a pretty good guess as to where it reads the arguments from if you know the calling conventions. Most likely they come from the fourth and fifth registers or from the stack somewhere below the return address.

Comment: Interesting, Thanks guys !!

Answer (score 0):

In your statement

```
 snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), str);
```

the format string contains conversion specifiers (`%x`), but corresponding arguments are missing. So, this invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1/p2,

> [....] If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is
>   undefined. [...]

You need to write

```
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), str, <list of arguments matching the conversion specifier>);
```

Check the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

undefined behavior, as because you have passed wong arguments snprintf() don't match the format string.